# jQuery if div display:none then get data-attribute and apply as class

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to use jquery to detect screen resize, then if my `span` is hidden then fire an event to take a `data-attribute` and apply as a class.

My HTML

```
<nav class="primary_nav group">
    <ul class="group smart-nav">
        <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="screen-clark" data-tip="tooltip" data-class="small">Clark Kent</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="screen-tony" data-class="medium">Tony Stark</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="javascript:;" class="screen-builder" data-class="large">Bob the Builder</a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="secondary_control">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="s-icon" title="Poke Bob" href="#"><span>Poke Bob</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="s-icon" title="Build Ironman" href="#"><span>Build Ironman</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="s-icon" title="Poke Bob" href="#"><span>Poke Bob</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.secondary_control ul {
  margin: 0;
  display: table;
  height: 58px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  top: 0;
}
.secondary_control ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.secondary_control ul li a {
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .secondary_control
  ul li a span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
if ($(".secondary_control ul li a span").css("display") == "none" ){
    $('.smart-nav li a').attr('class', $(this).data('tip'));
}
});
```

**Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/d3KQu/4/

Try resizing the window until the media query kicks in. You will notice the span is hidden and the text is removed. However, the data-attribute is not being applied as a class. Can anyone point out whats wrong, or how to improve. Many thanks.

**Update**
Thanks to help from a few people below, i've now got:

```
onResize = function() {
    if ($(".secondary_control ul li a span").is(":visible")){
        $('.smarter-nav li a').each(function(){ //loop through each
            if ($(this).hasClass("tooltip")){ // check if class is applied
                $(this).removeClass("tooltip"); //remove as :visible means screen is full width
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        $('.smarter-nav li a').each(function(){ //loop
            $(this).addClass($(this).attr('data-tip')); //add tooltip class
        });
    }
}//end function
```

Anyone who can improve this, make it more efficient, or correct any mistakes, please let me know. I am keen to learn. I've made it into a function and create and if statement to check if class is applied on resize so i can constantly check if span is:visible and when it's not make sure the class is being applied. When the window is larger, the span is visible and the if statement should remove the class again.

Comment: IMO, check for visibility with `.is(":visible")`

Comment: @tymeJV Why is this better than what I've opted for? Just want to know for future reference

Comment: $(this) refer to ".secondary_control ul li a span", but these elements don't have any data attribute. If you want to use the data attribute of ".smart-nav li a", you will have to use .each loop.

Comment: @Mat-visual - It's faster :) -- http://jsperf.com/visibility-checking

Comment: why do you set the class using the data-attribute and remove it directly with "tooltip"? Is that the only class you want to work with?

Comment: The object may have other classes but it's the only class i need to add yeh. Good question that, now i think about it, i am not sure..

Comment: so you want to add the class from the data attribute and then remove that same class that was added when your spans are visible?

Comment: and which attribute defines the class? you only have one element with data-tip, but all have data-class, I'm assuming it's the latter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35825/discussion-between-mat-visual-and-koala-dev)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simplified version of your function, it will add or remove the class from the `data-tip` attribute depending on the visibility of the spans:

```
onResize = function() {
    var addClass = !$(".secondary_control ul li a span").is(":visible")
    $('.smart-nav li a').each(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass($(this).data('tip'),addClass);
    });
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3KQu/7/)**

Note that the demo uses the `data-class` as the attributes as I found it easier to setup some CSS classes to test it that way

Comment: Super clean, love this. Thank you very much. Just one question if i may. If i wanted to fire another function i have once the class is added, is there an easy way with this to add in that call when it's adding the class from data-tip?

Comment: Depends of what kind of function, do you need to act upon the current link during the loop? and only when the class is added?

Comment: well, ideally I would fire a function once class is added, then destroy when class is remove. It's not essential, just trying to learn as much as possible !

Comment: Well you can't destroy a function so I assume you want to perform some action when the class is added and some other action when it's removed, if that's the case then you can store the boolean value of your span's visibility check and add an if statement, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/d3KQu/8/. Actually I've updated my answer as I believe it's best to have that value stored in a variable instead of making the check on every item

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you are trying to get the data (`data('tip')`) from the wrong element:

```
$('.smart-nav li a').attr('class', $(this).data('tip'));
```

`$(this)`  in your code is `$(window)`.

Change your code to:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(".secondary_control ul li a span").css("display") == "none") {
        $('.smart-nav li a').each(function(){
            $(this).addClass($(this).attr('data-tip'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This works pretty well. The only problem is, the class being added overwrites any existing classes. And when you make the window bigger, the class isn't removed. I am guessing that .attr overwrites classes, therefore i'd need .addClass?

Comment: Yeah you should use `addClass`. I changed that in my answer. When do you know that the class needs to be removed?

Comment: I'll update what im playing with at the moment, added some more ifs, although not sure it's the cleanest way.